# How to save message from push notification even if user does not tap the notification?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I'm working with Swift 3 in Xcode Version 8.1 (8B62).

Have been stuck on this for a really long time:
When I send a push notification with data through to the app I'm building and the app is in foreground, everything works as it should. When the app is in the background and I tap the push notification that comes in, everything works fine. However, whenever I open the app without tapping the notification, the message doesn't get saved. This is a problem not only when user doesn't tap the notification, but when multiple notifications come in, user is only able to tap one of them, and the rest are lost.

My app is a messaging app that saves the messages on the phone only (not in any central database so that it could pull from there to update every time the app comes into foreground).

Below is the code I'm using for this inside of AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FIRApp.configure()

    let notificationTypes : UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

    return true
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable : Any]){
    let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState

    if state == .background {
        print("I'm in the background place")
        updateNewMessage(data: data)
    }
    else if state == .active {
        print("I'm in the active place")
        updateNewMessage(data: data)
    }
    else if state == .inactive{
        print("I'm in the inactive statement")
        updateNewMessage(data: data)
    }
    else{
        print("I'm in the else statement")
        updateNewMessage(data: data)
    }

}
```

The updateNewMessage(data: data) function just does what's necessary to upload the message from the data to the internal SQL database of the phone.

Also a few things that happen:
when message comes in while phone is in foreground, the print statement "I'm in the active place" shows up, when user taps on the notification while screen is off or app in background "I'm in the inactive statement" prints out.

From everything I've been reading, people are saying that the way to go here is to use the in addition to didReceiveRemoteNotification,

```
fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void
```

however when trying to use those together, I'm not able to upload the message received even when user taps the notification (unless I'm doing it wrong...)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: did you find any solution , then kindly share it